# How do I pass the model type in boost beast websocket

Tags: c++, boost, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, boost-beast

I am working with c++11, beast library and IBM speech to text web service.

The websocket interface (to connect) needs the `authentication token` as request header while the handshake is performed.

Refering to [this code](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-websockets#WSopen) available in the Watson documents it looks like I have to pass the model type (if I want to) as request header too

```
var IAM_access_token = '{access_token}';
var wsURI = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize'
     + '?access_token=' + IAM_access_token
     + '&model=es-ES_BroadbandModel';
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsURI);
```

Also there is a [curl request format](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-models#modelsExample) mentioned to set the **"model"**

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}"
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary @{path}audio-file.flac
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_NarrowbandModel"
```

Can someone hel me figure out How do I pass "model" in my websocket (using beast in c++11)?

Here is how I am passing the authentication token:

```
mWebSocket.async_handshake_ex(mHost, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize",
        [mToken](request_type& reqHead) {
            reqHead.insert(http::field::authorization,mToken);},
        bind(&IbmWebsocketSession::send_start, shared_from_this(), placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: just add it to the url as in the examples?

Comment: @AlanBirtles You can put it as answer. it solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ALanBirtles suggested

Putting the resuired `model` in the url as

```
    mWebSocket.async_handshake_ex(mHost, "/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_NarrowbandModel",...
```

**Works**